# Images & Videos on Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload images and videos from the photos & videos storage on the phone to firebase storage and I have not been able to. And after being able to, I want to be able to post on a chat app to be seen like on twitter-- Android Studio. PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: That's a bit broad to answer on Stack Overflow. But you could do worse than starting with the Firebase codelab: https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/#codelabs

Comment: @Frank   I have no idea to go about this problem that I am facing so yes, it may be very vague but I need all the help I can get so please, if you don't mind, would it be possible for you to be able to answer my question. Thank You. I am sorry I am pretty new at this and my wuestions may seem dumb and vague.

Answer (score 1):

Google for this youtube channel "TVAC Studio" and follow his firebase tutorials. It's insightful for beginners.

You won't be able to do a chat message app simply by follow his tutorial, but he doea a thorough run through for uploading and retrieving all the data you want (He teaches Audio files and images).

So after running through his video series, you'll only have to think about binding each file to the user who uploaded it and to think about how to bind messages and users to a chat node for the database.

Think thoroughly for the database structure.

Cheers